# Change a parameter in document using the cmd?

Tags: external-files

I need to be able to change the value of a parameter inside a LaTeX document without having to change it manually. I'll explain:

There is one main program that executes another smaller one. This smaller program computes some things and creates a .txt-file with a specific name and all its results inside. Then the main program executes the LaTeX file I have to create which will process the created .txt-file into a nice pdf (using commands such as `\openin\txtfile=\filename.txt` and the package `datatool`).
Problem is that LaTeX needs to know the name of the newly created .txt-file. The main program knows the name it and will call the LaTeX file by using the cmd command `> latex texfile.tex`. But this won't change the value of `\filename` in any way.

Is there actually any possible way to change a value (of `\filename`) inside the LaTeX file using the cmd? Because I have absolutely no clue and Google doesn't help me either...

Comment: You do `pdflatex \def\filename{abc}\input{texfile}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer) for the solution:

```
> pdflatex \cmd\input{texfile}
```

`\cmd` can be any command `LaTeX` recognizes. And `input{texfile}` pastes all contents of `texfile.tex` into the cmd.

Answer (score 0):

Potentially you might want to change the `jobname`

latex -jobname=$filename texfile.tex

where $filename is the name of your .txt file. Then inside your .tex file you could use

```
\openin\txtfile=\jobname
```

This approach would change the name of the final output and all auxiliary files from texfile.* to $filename.*, which may or may not be desirable.